# Confused as to the waiting period required after getting an order

Tags: canada, small-claims-court, british-columbia, court-order

A default judgement was awarded. It seems there are contradicting orders in how much time one must wait to get it enforced:

> As set out in 58.1 (3) of the CRTA, a part may only enforce this order
> if the time for making a notice of objection has passed and a Notice
> of Objection has not been filed. **The party in default has no right to
> make a Notice of Object**, as set out in section [56.1(2.1)](https://www.bclaws.ca/civix/document/id/complete/statreg/12025_01#section56.1) of the CRTA.

However I was also told

> **Please note that you may only enforce this order if the time for making a Notice of Objection has
> passed.** Please be advised that a Notice of Objection may be made by a
> participating party in a small claims proceeding who disagrees with
> the decision issued by the Civil Resolution Tribunal (CRT).

These seem to contradict. This is a default judgment, and the other party did default. So doesn't the first paragraph apply and it can be enforced it ASAP? I asked the tribunal and they basically said hire a lawyer if I don't understand the decision.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> doesn't the first paragraph apply and it can be enforced it ASAP?

The first excerpt applies, but that does not mean that judgment is enforceable immediately. Section 56.1(2.1) reflects the possibility that "*the default is set aside by the tribunal*". This is likely to occur if the counterparty proves that a reasonable cause prevented him from addressing the complaint.

As for contradictions between first and second excerpts, there is none. The second excerpt refers to a *participating* party. Obtaining a default judgment suggests that the counterparty did not appear (and therefore did not *participate*) in the proceedings.